# Azure DevOps Delivery Plans for on-premises

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to enable "Delivery Plans" for on-premises implementation of DevOps on DevOps 2020 1.2?

Comment: Did you refer to the [documentation on delivery plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops), which answers your question?

Comment: The only real issue here is that you did not provide enough information nor cite any sources you may have found while attempting to research this yourself.

Comment: The only real issue here is that you did not provide enough information nor cite any sources you may have found while attempting to research this yourself.

Comment: I apologize if the information is incomplete.  I should've added more information.  I reviewed the link provided.   

After installing "Delivery Plans" extension, I don't see the "Delivery Plans" menu item under "Boards".  I was trying to see if there is an option that I missed where I need to manually enable this menu item by project.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Delivery Plans extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Please go the Collection Settings - Extensions, then click the `browse marketplace` button. In this way you will be connected with the azure devops server identity.

Search the Delivery Plans extension and Get it free. The extension will be installed if you have the required permission. See more here: [Delivery Plans 1.0 Marketplace extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/extensions/delivery-plans?view=azure-devops-2020)

Comment: After installing "Delivery Plans" extension, I don't see the "Delivery Plans" menu item under "Boards". I was trying to see if there is an option that I missed where I need to manually enable this menu item by project.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the question.  I see that the menu is now renamed to "Plans" instead of Delivery Plans.

I also had to make changes to Security as shown in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/edit-delivery-plan-permissions?view=azure-devops-2022

Thank you for all your responses.